# Has anyone found a workaround for the Cordova Android keyboard bug?

Tags: android, cordova, keyboard

I have built 2 separate apps using Cordova 6.3.1, and I've noticed a strange bug with the keyboard. The following has only been tested on two separate Samsung Galaxy S6 phones running Android 6.0.1. It only occurs on WebApps, not web pages.

In any text input or textarea, typing a special character will automatically replace the next non-special character typed with the same special character:

1) Type a special character (e.g. *)

2) Type any other non-special character (e.g. a)

3) This character is automatically replaced with the preceding special character (e.g. *a -> **)

I've also noticed that if I type a non-special character followed by a special character, then delete the special character, then type another non-special character. This last non-special character is replaced with the first non-special character.

Crazier things happen if you type a long string of non-special characters ending with a special character and then try this delete some number of times and type a non-special character. I haven't been able to find the pattern though.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is there a workaround? Does this happen on other phones and OSs?

Thanks for your help!

UPDATE:

I tested this on a Samsung Galaxy S4 mini running Android 4.4.2, and it did NOT exhibit the bug.

Comment: Have you checked the predictive typing / autocorrect settings? Seems weird that it would behave differently in a browser than in the app, though.

Comment: Yeah. It really only happens on Cordova apps. I also don't think it's autocorrect because of the crazy unpredictability that happens in the long string case. I don't understand it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug on [Chrome WebView](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=659934), it seems to be fixed days ago. You can check the cordova [bug report thread](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12060?jql=status%20%3D%20Open%20AND%20text%20~%20%22samsung%20keyboard%22).